# ScrollView Height does not wrap onto parent activity in code

Tags: java, android

I have this little problem regarding layout with scroll view on my android code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class ScheduleList extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    setTheme(R.style.DefaultForm);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    String data[] = { "Android", "iPhone", "BlackBerry", "AndroidPeople" };
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    sv.addView(lv);
    sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(sv);
}
}
```

And this is what I get 
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spLx0.jpg)

How do I resize this ScrollView to match height into my activity form, I did change the LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT and also LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT on setLayoutParams but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, questions about code implementations belong on StackOverflow. Admins will migrate it, so please don't double post there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Execute :

```
 sv.addView(lv);
 sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Outside of `onCreate()` or the **constructor !**
Because the view isn't finish to be created and view don't know the size of the element !

For example if you try to print `sv.getWidth()` the method will be to *return 0* in the **constructor** or in the `onCreate()` but the good size if the call is outside !

Comment: I try to call the code to resize it from onResume(), onStart(), onPostResume() or any posibble event but it fail with exception. Any suggest ?

Comment: you can't call this into onResume() or other same type of method because the view isn't created ! don't have solution if you don't call this outside the view initialization. Think to another way ! :)